# Retrieve Firebase Testlab testcase

Tags: firebase, gcloud, testcase, firebase-test-lab

I am triggering UI test in Firebase testlab from Jenkins using Google CLI command. It works all good following instructions from  https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/continuous#using_with_jenkins_ci .

now i want to get the list of testcases executed so i can use the result for reportinng via Jenkins.

Any Suggesstion or guidance on how to retrieve the test cases will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to retrieve test results programmatically, you have a couple options.

1. Download the junit XML file(s) from your results bucket.
2. Access test case data using the [Cloud Tool Results API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/reference/toolresults/rest)

Comment: Thanks @p-davis .. since folders are created based on timestamp it was bit difficult for retrieving the xml file but using `--results-dir` in `gcloud firebase test android run` command will give flexibilty to access generated xml file using  `gsutil cp <source> <dest>`

Comment: That's correct, you'll likely want to use `--results-dir` (and optionally `--results-bucket`) if you want a predictable path to the results. Just be sure to use a unique value for `--results-dir` for every test invocation.
Harder, but still possible, you could parse the results URL with the timestamp out of the `gcloud` command's stderr output.